# Handling salt with spring security PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I was suprised to see that the Spring Security PasswordEncoder (the implementation I use is BCryptPasswordEncoder if this makes a difference) generates a salt when encoding passwords.

What I don't get is, how am I supposed to obtain this salt when validating login requests? I meant to use my own salt, but (presumably) because of the automatic salt generation, I get different hash values for the same password+salt combination.

I'm a bit confused, and don't know how the encoder should be used properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the builtin validation logic, not writing your own password validation functions. Hence you shouldn't need to obtain the salt that Spring Security generates. See the documentation in `PasswordEncoder`:

```
/**
 * Verify the encoded password obtained from storage matches the submitted raw
 * password after it too is encoded. Returns true if the passwords match, false if
 * they do not. The stored password itself is never decoded.
 *
 * @param rawPassword the raw password to encode and match
 * @param encodedPassword the encoded password from storage to compare with
 * @return true if the raw password, after encoding, matches the encoded password from
 * storage
 */
boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword);
```